# Complex Numbers and their Conjugates

Tags: complex-numbers

How many complex numbers are there that are conjugates of their own cubes? Is there some simple way to find this?

Comment: So you seek solutions of the equation $z = (z^3)^*$, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$z^3 = \bar z$ implies $|z|^3 = |\bar z| = |z|$. Hence $|z| = 1$ or $z = 0$.

Setting aside now the trivial case, this means we can write $z = e^{i\theta}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: And even better, when $|z|=1$ we have $\bar z=1/z$ so everything resolves to ordinary algebra.